# Soft-on/off circuit turns on on startup despite being jumpered to stay off, why?

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting

So, I am building the soft-on/off circuit shown below and described [here](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch) on a breadboard to test it out before I actually put it into a design.

[image: schematic given by source]

However, to better fit the parts on hand, I decided to alter a couple of the R and C values slightly, and use a pair of TO-220 FETs instead of the SO-8 dual FET, resulting in this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc3oYN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which yields the simulation results below when turned on without RL connected (NFG tracks Vout in both plots, so it's not shown):

[image: simulation plot, no-load]

and with RL connected for a 10mA load at full Vout (PFG, Vin, and PB track each other here):

[image: simulation plot, 10mA load]

However, when I prototype the same circuit that's in the simulation, without a load, I get this gem of a result on power-on:

[image: oscillogram of the misbehaving circuit]

Along with that, Vout comes up to a steady 12V, tracking Vin.  What in the world could I have done wrong here?  Is the circuit given really that sensitive to part selection?  Or how could I have miswired it to produce the results I'm receiving?  And where on Earth is that 370us pulse on PFG at startup coming from?

Comment: Is it really ZERO load? Because your Vout will go to Vin with zero current.

Comment: I have no load connected to the circuit whatsoever -- should I just hang a resistor off the output for testing purposes?

Comment: Please do that!

Comment: IMO, the transient is almost certainly the N-FET turning on.

Comment: Hey, I don't really want to be a dick about this, but I helped you solve your problem in under half an hour. Typically that kind of help is expen$ive. Could you at least credit me with the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments: I think you need a load for this circuit to work.

Shamelessly taking credit for this, here is an answer for you to mark :)

You should also take a look at Linear Technology's line of push button controllers. They are very low power and have worked well for me in the past.

Comment: The LTC pushbutton controllers are indeed nice-looking parts -- if I was going for a design where ease of hand assembly wasn't a prime concern, I'd have sprung for them in a heartbeat.

Comment: If you need to cut off battery power completely (down to a few uA) they are perfect, and they allow your microcontroller to turn the device off, which is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is indeed the no-load behavior of the circuit that is causing my issue!  (Why does the sim show it coming up to ~3.75V?)  I put a 1KΩ, >=1W resistor from the output to ground, and I get no voltage at the output and no stray pulse on the PFET gate, as seen in the oscillogram below:

[image: oscillogram of the circuit with a 1kΩ load resistor in place]

Comment: I think the load (at 10mA) is just high enough that you're getting 8V of drop across the PFET. You just happened to pick a very marginal number.

Comment: And it looks like, at start-up, there is some high-frequency ringing or oscillation happening, especially on the first image. Stick a ferrite bead on the gate pins and see if that gets rid of it... might impact the rest of the circuit behavior as well.